# What happens when a node's H2 database gets deleted by some means in Corda?

Tags: corda

Imagine A is in a network along with B and C. And A has one shared fact with B, and one shared fact with C. Both these are residing in A's Vault. Suppose, A's system gets crashed and node's H2 data is gone, how can A recover the same with both these facts back in its Vault ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If B and C were both willing to re-share this information with A, they could both call a flow such as the one defined below to resend the transactions and their dependencies to A:

```
@InitiatingFlow
@StartableByRPC
class ShareTransactionHistory(val otherParty: Party, val signedTransaction: SignedTransaction) : FlowLogic<Unit>() {
    @Suspendable
    override fun call() {
        val otherPartySession = initiateFlow(otherParty)
        subFlow(SendTransactionFlow(otherPartySession, signedTransaction))
    }
}

@InitiatedBy(ShareTransactionHistory::class)
class ShareTransactionHistoryResponder(val otherPartySession: FlowSession) : FlowLogic<Unit>() {
    @Suspendable
    override fun call() {
        subFlow(ReceiveTransactionFlow(otherPartySession, statesToRecord = StatesToRecord.ONLY_RELEVANT))
    }
}
```

A will then automatically re-record the transactions and any relevant states.

However, please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50034385) for caveats in the restoration process.